# Creating Discount Coupons in Kentico 7

Tags: c#, kentico

So I'm trying to create discount coupons for a Kentico 7 site, and I'm not sure if I'm completely misunderstanding how the DiscountCouponInfoProvider works, or if I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
var newCoupon = new DiscountCouponInfo {
    //Fill in data fields here
};
DiscountCouponInfoProvider.SetDiscountCouponInfo(newCoupon);
```

This doesn't throw an error, but the coupon never shows up in the database. A few lines down I use

```
var result = DiscountCouponInfoProvider.GetDiscountCouponinfo();
```

passing in the same ID I used when creating the coupon, and it stores all of the correct information in result.

I noticed that there is an insert method for the DiscountCouponInfo class

```
newCoupon.Insert();
```

which may be closer to what I'm looking for, but haven't tried yet.

Any help would be appreciated. Or a link to the Kentico 7 api reference. Every time I go looking for it I keep finding the Kentico 8.1 api reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create coupons within the Kentico UI by going to CMS Desk > Ecommerce > Discount Coupons. However, if you are needing to create them outside the UI for some reason, then you were pretty close.  You will want to use an Info object along with the InfoProvider object, like this:

```
    // Instantiate an info object
    DiscountCouponInfo dci = new DiscountCouponInfo();

    // Set your properties
    dci.DiscountCouponDisplayName = "Some text";
    dci.DiscountCouponValue = 10;

    //Update the DB with an InfoProvider object
    DiscountCouponInfoProvider.SetDiscountCouponInfo(dci);
```

The Info object is just a simple data container that you can instantiate, populate with data, then pass it as an argument to an InfoProvider object.

The InfoProvider then has methods for update/creating records, etc.

You could also populate an Info object with data from the Kentico DB like this:

```
    DiscountCouponInfo dci = new DiscountCouponInfoProvider.GetDiscountCouponInfo(DiscountCouponID);
```

I actually JUST wrote a [blog post](http://jerreck.me/kentico-infoproviders/) about this.  Feel free to check it out or [read](http://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/older-documentation) [Kentico's](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html) [docs](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Database+table+API) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. The blog post was very well written. I read through some of the other posts as well and I like your style, especially your first post. The same exact problem is why my blog never launched, I focused too much on trying to write the perfect first post, and ended up with nothing at all. Maybe I'll revisit that idea.